# FitBounds doesnt work in googlemaps javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, fitbounds

I have a map and a list of markers, each of which has a position in LatLng object. The position is valid because i can see the markers on the map. However i want to fit the map to the markers so i use the proper syntax as below.
However the map never zooms and centers in those two positions. Instead it load in the initial center,zoom that i config in the initMap. Can anybody identify the problem please???

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(25.36234, 15.3623);
var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.2352, 12.36435);
bounds.extend(location2);
bounds.extend(location);
window.parent.map.fitBounds(bounds);
window.parent.map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

Comment: What is `window.parent.map`?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (if I replace those with `map` from [Google's Simple Map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) it works ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8d51bmet/4/)))

Answer (score 3):

`window.parent.map` seems a bit odd of a solution for your problem.

This should solve your problem.

```
var map;

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.5473234, 35.3796685),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });


  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(25.36234, 15.3623);
  var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.2352, 12.36435);
  bounds.extend(location2);
  bounds.extend(location);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

Comment: window.parent.map is set like that because the js where my code is written is in a child Frame and the map is defined in the Parent Frame.

Comment: How do you declare the map? Embedded maps work with a Google Maps URL. However if you only want for map to display specific data, you can generate a map from [link](https://www.mapsdirections.info/en/custom-google-maps/)

Comment: Declare the map is like in the code above. var map. Well this is written in a jsp of the parent frame and the code that i want to put the bounds is in a js of a child frame jsp. I have checked it...window.parent.map work fine!!

Comment: Can you do my way with just giving your iframe an "id"? If there's no cross-origin error, it should work in theory.

Comment: I finally solved it. The problem was that by the time i was adding markers to the map the map DIV was style: none.